# How should I partition a list?(Without using libraries)

Tags: haskell

How should I partition a list?(Without using libraries)

For example:

Input:

```
[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
```

Output:

```
[[0,1,1],[1,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a homework service. Make a fair attempt and come back
with *specific* questions about that attempt. See the
[*open letter to students with homework problems*](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively each time split the list after *n* elements, and then yield the first item, and recurse on the remaining items, so:

```
partition :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
partition n = go
    where go [] = []
          go xs = ys : go yss
              where (ys, yss) = splitAt n xs
```

For example:

```
ghci> partition 3 [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
[[0,1,1],[1,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

Comment: I'd like to ask one more thing about this, if i wanted to end a line every time the list is split, how should I edit the function? I've tried simply adding

do putStrLn " "

but that didnt work, I also tried writing a seperate endl function and putting that in, however i keep getting parse error. I'm assuming I don't understand something about syntax of functions in Haskell